# Most frequent word in one file which is not found in another file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program where I count the most frequently used words from one file but those words should not be available in another file. So basically I am reading data from test.txt file and counting the most frequently used word from that file, but that word should not be found in test2.txt file.

Below are sample data files, test.txt and test2.txt

test.txt:

```
The Project is for testing. doing some testing to find what's going on. the the the.
```

test2.txt:

```
a
about
above
across
after
afterwards
again
against
the
```

Below is my script, which parses files test.txt and test2.txt. It finds the most frequently used words from test.txt, excluding words found in test2.txt.

I thought I was doing everything right, but when I execute my script, it gives "the" as the most frequent word. But actually, the result should be "testing", as "the" is found in test2.txt but "testing" is not found in test2.txt.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

dgWords = re.findall(r'\w+', open('test.txt').read().lower())

f = open('test2.txt', 'rb')
sWords = [line.strip() for line in f]

print(len(dgWords));

for sWord in sWords:
    print (sWord)
    print (dgWords) 
    while sWord in dgWords: dgWords.remove(sWord)   

print(len(dgWords));
mostFrequentWord = Counter(dgWords).most_common(1)
print (mostFrequentWord)
```

Comment: When I run your solution, I do get 'testing' as most frequent word.

Comment: I should  add though - I am using StringIO - shouldn't make a difference though.

Comment: I still don't get 'testing' as most frequent word. I am still getting 'the' for some reason. can you help me why it can be? I am using Python 3.4.3 on windows 7.

Comment: Exactly the same code works on 'python 2.7' on Windows . I am afraid - I don't have python 3.x on Windows 7. BTW, what does your `len(dgWords)` prints? Are you passing `dgWords` to some function - making changes in function? and then outside the function you are using `dgWords`? That should explain the problem.

Comment: No. I am not passing dgWords to any outside function. Above code is all what I have. Both the time len(dbWords) is showing me same length which is weired and thats why i thought my solution is not working as it is not removing any words from dgWords. I am getting 2.7 on my machine to see how it goes on 2.7

Comment: Thank you @gabhijit. It works fine on python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd go about it - using sets

```
all_words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('test.txt').read().lower())

f = open('test2.txt', 'rb')
stop_words = [line.strip() for line in f]

set_all = set(all_words)
set_stop = set(stop_words)

all_only = set_all - set_stop

print Counter(filter(lambda w:w in all_only, all_words)).most_common(1)
```

This should be slightly faster as well as you do a counter on only 'all_only' words

Comment: Yes. Using as set works fine and I see it is much faster as well. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't get your comment - `Counter` is never O(some function of n)? So regardless of the length of the the iterator, `Counter` should be constant and also `Counter.most_common`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('test.txt') as testfile, open('test2.txt') as stopfile:
    stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in stopfile)
    words = Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', open('test.txt').read().lower()))
    for word in stopwords:
        if word in words:
            words.pop(word)
    print("the most frequent word is", words.most_common(1))
```

Comment: (python 3.4, win7 x64 eclipse PyDev)Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Bill\Programming\eclipse_windows\test\main.py", line 12, in <module>
        words.pop(word)
    KeyError: 'again'

Comment: @realtemper: Good catch. I'd forgotten an edge case. It's fixed now

Comment: Yes it worked. Besides, did `open('test.txt').read().lower()` meant `testfile.read().lower()`? I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed the following line of your original code

`f = open('test2.txt', 'rb')`

to

`f = open('test2.txt', 'r')`

and it worked. Simply read your text as string instead of binaries. Otherwise they won't match in regex. Tested on python 3.4 eclipse PyDev Win7 x64.

OFFTOPIC:

It's more pythonic to open files using **with** statements. In this case, write

`with open('test2.txt', 'r') as f:`

and indent file processing statements accordingly. That should keep you away from forgetting to close the filestream.

Comment: Thank you for comment. It works fine on Python 2.7 and after your change, it works fine on Python 3.X also. Thank you.